# Bake a image appearing in a mirror

Tags: texturing, baking, osl

is It possible to bake a image appearing in a mirror from a certain angle of camera? What is the possible ways to do that? Can I do from OSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, but it depends on neither light nor the camera changing (but you can get around this problem by animating the texture). Just bake your rendered result from the angle you want, and apply the texture to that plane.